# ReactiveTableViewCell with dynamic height against cell reuse : how to avoid falling in an infinite loop?

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, reactiveui, prepareforreuse

So here's the description of the loop my app keeps falling on:

There is a UITableView containing ReactiveTableViewCell's (but I think RX part doesn't really matter here, so let's pretend these are UITableViewCell). Each cell embeds a UITextField upon an **expandable/collapsable** UIView (that allows me to show any error message related to the textfield) - when there is no error to show, this subview is **collapsed**.

The thing is, when UITableView gets scrolled and makes **reuse** of an "errored" cell, the subview of this cell is still **expanded**. As PrepareForReuse() method is made to reset cell state before a reuse, I thought it would be the right place to collapse the subview, and indeed it does... until the app falls into a loop, resizing top-screen and bottom-screen same cell forever.

How do you think I could fix this issue? Maybe is there a way to increase cell reuse tolerance so UITableView won't reuse a cell as soon as it disappeared from screen? Maybe shall I have a try with a resize-lock while list is being scrolled, but it will always leave some margin for error so it's not the fix I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

Well, it seems like the RX part was not so clueless. The IObservable I was subscribing to, aiming to show the error message, was a ReplaySubject. It appears that looping was happening on there due to this little guy, refreshing the UITableView (through TV.BeginUpdates/TV.EndUpdates) endlessly. So by now I assume ReplaySubject and cell-reuse won't work well altogether, since a simple replacement with a BehaviorSubject fixed the issue.